# How to tell pipedream to upload a content to google drive?

Tags: pipedream

I have a workflow that transcribes audio files to markdown and LaTeX. The result is send to me via email. Works well.

Now I want to store the results in google drive.

The component doesn't offer that possibility only the tmp folder. But how do I get the data there?

I tried this node js code snippet without success:

```
// To use any npm package, just import it
import fs from "fs"

export default defineComponent({
  async run({ steps, $ }) {
    // Reference previous step data using the steps object and return data to use it in future steps
  fs.writeFileSync('/tmp/text_transcription.md', steps.chat.$return_value.generated_message.content);
  return steps.trigger.event
  },
})
```